# MS Office file types icon dll location

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-10, dll, file-types

Help!
Some months ago i messed around and used Types to change some file type icons without making a system restore. I changed the Excel, Powerpoint, Onenote, Word, Access and Publisher file type icons. They look ugly and I realized how stupid I was so I wanted to change back.

I'm not using Types now, but FileTypesMan. The problem is I can't find the location the dll containing the icons are.

I'm using MS Office 13 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nirsoft, who developed FileTypesMan, has another program you could try called IconsExtract. I dont have Office 13, but i tried it out on 14 and was able to locate all the office icons and change them with FileTypesMan.

Using IconsExtact, browse to and search the folder C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office 13/ (or something similar to that).  It may take a minute but a list of all the office icons should show up.

Select the icons you want to use, right click and save them to your Desktop or another folder as a .ico extension.

You can then use FileTypesMan to edit the extension's icon. Browse to the folder where you saved the icons and choose the appropriate .ico file.

Alternatively you could try to rebuild the icon cache, or reinstall office, but Im not positive these options will work.

If your still stuck, try downloading Office Ico files from the net and loading them with FileTypesMan.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same the problem, but for Outlook 2016. After some searching (with IconsExtract, as mentioned in an answer above) I found several locations which store icons used in the program.

I don't know whether they are the same as in 2013 (and have no way of validating that now), but for those who may have a similar problem in the future, a considerable number of the icons are stored in:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\1033\OUTLLIBR.DLL
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OLKFSTUB.dll

As for the other microsoft office applications:

**For excel:**
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\XLICONS.EXE

**For access:**
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ACCICONS.EXE
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE

**For word:**
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WWLIB.DLL
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WORDICON.EXE
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE

**For publisher:**
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\1033/PUB6INTL.DLL
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSPUB.EXE

**For powerpoint:**
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\PPTICO.EXE
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE

**For onenote:**
I cannot find much for onenote, except its application file(s):
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ONENOTE.EXE
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ONENOTEM.EXE
However, having looked at it, most of the other icons can be found in the other dlls and exes already.

If you are looking specifically for something that looks like the file icons, then you either need to look in Shell.dll in the Windows32 folder, or in this folder:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\LogoImages

Answer (score 1):

For the location of icons see below MSO 2019

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\VFS\Windows\Installer

Answer (score 0):

Win 10 with Office 2013 user here.  Icons found at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We definitely appreciate all of the contributions from our community members, but could you please elaborate just a bit more?  For example, which files is the OP looking for?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: In case you don't know, ["OP" means the person who asked the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146513/349538).

Answer (score 0):

I was not getting the Outlook Icon while attaching a .msg file in word 2016. My issue was resolved after selecting C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\1033\MAPISHELLR.DLL  in Change Icon button.
Now Outlook picks up proper icon with .msg file

Answer (score -2):

For Office16 I went to the office16 directory (in Program Files x86). There are separate exe (aka Application)  files there for each Office component that end with ICO or ICON (ACCICONS, PPTICO, WORDICON) that have the icons. Couldn't find one with all icons. The inconsistencies (ICONS, ICO, ICON) are not mine btw.